# Form Authenticate user should not see specific site pages

Tags: forms-authentication

I have a SharePoint site works with both Form user and windows user. I have a login page (application page in 15 folder). The site is fully anonymous now. Everything works fine. The problem is When form users try to access the SharePoint site pages directly with ur like (/pages/***.aspx) they are able to see the page, which I don't want to see them unless they are logged in. Please help.

Please not at some exception I want to users to seethe site pages. for example footer text stored in site page need to be visible for users before they logged in

Basically I want some site pages to be visible before they logged but rest need to be authenticated before visiting the page.